# Display native validation message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, html

I'm currently developing a form which will be powered by HTML5 features and jQuery. One of the things I've been tasked with is ensuring that the native "Please fill in this field" message is still available to browsers which natively support validation.

My setup looks like so:

```
|----------|
|   FORM   |
|----------|
===BUTTON===
```

The form has several parts to it, and so the button is `global` across them all. The form then slides to the next section if complete.

Here is what I have now, this correctly fires the button event to the form and triggers a `submit` event.

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    var $incoming = $(".nextPart #" + (currentSlide));
    var incomingID = $incoming.data("cardid");
    var partCode = "form-" + incomingID;

    $("form[name='" + partCode + "']").trigger("submit");
});

$("form").bind('submit', function(event) {
    var goForth = true;

    if(!event.currentTarget.checkValidity()) goForth = false;

    if(!goForth) return false;

    /* Do some stuff with progress bar and more things */

    return true;
});
```

However, even though the form submit fails, there is no validation message. Is there a way to pragmatically fire this on an element, or have I done something stupid?

For clarification, this is a screenshot of the validation message I am on about.
[image]

Comment: `event.currentTarget` is a DOM node -- have you given it the `checkValidity` property ?

Comment: No, but when I used `console.log()` it displayed that as a property.

Comment: is that property a function -- `typeof event.currentTarget == 'function'`

Comment: `false` and `console.log(typeof event.currentTarget);` reports an `object`

Comment: +1 for having a variable reference called `goForth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I described in my first post, I was using a `click` event on a button which was in a global scope. This was then sending a `submit` action to the form which, although was sending the form to be submitted, it wasn't firing the bubble event (whatever the hell that is) on the elements.

To fix this, I wrapped all of my *slides* in one form instead of multiples. I kept my submit button outside of the slides, so it still acted as a *global* navigation item.

Removing the `click` event from this button and changing the type of it to `submit` now gets the bubble displaying.

Not the best fix, since the bubble should be able to be trigged without having to submit the form, however, I guess with HTML5 validation, you can define the parameters for what is accepted and what isn't.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `event.currentTarget.checkValidity` -- do this...

```
function checkValidity(elem) {
 // check validity here
 // retun true/false
}
```

and then in your submit handler do this...

```
if(checkValidity(event.currentTarget)) { ...
```

Also, it is generally NOT a good idea to `trigger` native browser events -- `trigger` is good for custom events -- if you need to submit the form you can call the `submit()` method of the form object like this..

```
$("form[name='" + partCode + "']").get(0).submit();
```

Comment: This doesn't really help me in showing the validation message, I'm capable of manually validating myself, but since there is no way of doing what I want, in the format I have, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I've actually unaccepted your answer because the way I fixed this wasn't really linked to what you suggested.